# Why are my variables not being calculated properly?

Tags: c

I'm making a simple program for class to be able to find out the new mayor/president based on an electoral college based system.The input into my array and the subsequent output of the table of results all work perfectly but...My variables aStatesWon, bStatesWon, cStatesWon and dStatesWon (For Candidates A,B,C&D respectively) are not being calculated properly even though i thought i had them calculating correctly. I'm getting figures similar to -2324252 or 62341 not something like 2 or 3 like i'm expecting. Here's the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#define STATES 5
#define CANDIDATES 4


void declareNewMayor(int aStatesWon,int bStatesWon,int cStatesWon, int dStatesWon);

void main() {

    int votes[STATES][CANDIDATES];
    int StateWon = -1;
    int StateWinner;
    int aStatesWon = 0;
    int bStatesWon = 0;
    int cStatesWon = 0;
    int dStatesWon = 0;
    int newMayor;

    FILE* open;

    int i,j;


    for (i = 0; i < STATES; i++)
    {
        StateWinner = 0;
        StateWon = -1;

        for (j = 0; j < CANDIDATES; j++)
        {
            printf("Please enter the votes for candidate %d for state %d\n",(j+1),(i + 1));
            scanf("%d",&votes[i][j]);
            if (votes[i][j] > StateWon)
            {
                StateWon = votes[i][j];
                StateWinner = j;
            } //see if the won that state
        }
        printf("Winner of State %d is Candidate %d\n",i,j);
        if (StateWinner = 0)
        {
            aStatesWon++;
        }
        else if (StateWinner = 1)
        {
            bStatesWon++;
        }
        else if (StateWinner = 2)
        {
            cStatesWon++;

        }
        else if (StateWinner = 3)
        {
            dStatesWon++;

        }//increase number of states won by that candidate if the won that state

        printf("States Won  A:%d  B:%d   C:%d   D:%d", aStatesWon, bStatesWon, cStatesWon, dStatesWon);

    }//enter in votes for each candidate for each state
    open = fopen("votes.txt", "w");
    if (open == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nFile could not be opened\n");
    }
    else
    {

        printf("STATES CANDIDATE A    CANDIDATE B    CANDIDATE C    CANDIDATE D\n");
        fprintf(open,"STATES CANDIDATE A    CANDIDATE B    CANDIDATE C    CANDIDATE D\n");
        for (i = 0; i < STATES; i++)
        {
            printf("STATE %d", (i + 1));
            fprintf(open,"STATE %d", (i + 1));

            for (j = 0; j < CANDIDATES; j++)
            {
                printf("          %d       ", votes[i][j]);
                fprintf(open,"          %d       ", votes[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");




        }//print out table
    }

    declareNewMayor(aStatesWon,bStatesWon,cStatesWon,dStatesWon);





}//main
void declareNewMayor(int aStatesWon, int bStatesWon, int cStatesWon, int dStatesWon)
{

    char winner;
    int statesWon;

    if (aStatesWon > bStatesWon&&aStatesWon > cStatesWon&&aStatesWon > dStatesWon)
    {

        statesWon = aStatesWon;
        winner = "A";
    }
    else if (bStatesWon > aStatesWon&&bStatesWon > cStatesWon&&bStatesWon > dStatesWon) {


        statesWon = bStatesWon;
        winner = "B";
    }
    else if (cStatesWon > aStatesWon&&cStatesWon > bStatesWon&&cStatesWon > dStatesWon) {


        statesWon = cStatesWon;
        winner = "C";
    }
    else if (dStatesWon > aStatesWon&&dStatesWon > cStatesWon&&dStatesWon > aStatesWon) {


        statesWon = dStatesWon;
        winner = "C";
    }


    printf("The new Mayor is candiate %c with %d states won!", winner,statesWon);



}//calculate new mayor and declare it
```

Comment: There are a couple of problems with your code. First of all, `void main()` seems off. Secondly, you should've first used a debugger to debug your code yourself. Lastly, are you aware of a [mcve] requirement? This seems far off from *Minimal*. Most of the time, while construcing a minimal example, you find the bug yourself, which is also why you should contruct one.

Comment: what is your compiler? If gcc, I suggest `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror` and fix your code.

Answer (score 1):

There are some logic errir in your function `declareNewMayor`.

1> You assigned the string literal to character variable `winner`. It will result an undefined behavior

```
 winner = "A";
 winner = "B";
 winner = "C";
```

So should be replaced by:

```
 winner = 'A';
 winner = 'B';
 winner = 'B';
```

2> if ... else in the function `declareNewMayor`. You don't check other cases. For example: `aStatesWon == bStatesWon == cStatesWon == dStatesWon`. How is the result in that case? if you don't care other cases, you can initialize 2 variables `winner`, `statesWon` with some value that avoid the undefined behavior with uninitialized variable (that is reason why your output is strange with -2324252 or 62341). Here is my solution

```
void declareNewMayor(int aStatesWon, int bStatesWon, int cStatesWon, int dStatesWon)
{

char winner = '?';
int statesWon = 0;

if (aStatesWon > bStatesWon&&aStatesWon > cStatesWon&&aStatesWon > dStatesWon)
{

    statesWon = aStatesWon;
    winner = 'A';
}
else if (bStatesWon > aStatesWon&&bStatesWon > cStatesWon&&bStatesWon > dStatesWon) {


    statesWon = bStatesWon;
    winner = 'B';
}
else if (cStatesWon > aStatesWon&&cStatesWon > bStatesWon&&cStatesWon > dStatesWon) {


    statesWon = cStatesWon;
    winner = 'C';
}
else if (dStatesWon > aStatesWon&&dStatesWon > cStatesWon&&dStatesWon > aStatesWon) {


    statesWon = dStatesWon;
    winner = 'D';
}


printf("The new Mayor is candiate %c with %d states won!", winner,statesWon);



}//calculate new mayor and declare it
```